# Integrate Screen Manager Widget with MapView

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

### The concept of application

I'm trying to create an application which in the initial stage will consist of 2 windows.

**The first window** (*LoginScreen*) is a login window with a button that when you click it takes you to the second window.

**The second window** (*MapScreen*) should display a map using the MapView widget.

### Description of the problem

After starting the application, the LoginScreen works correctly.

After moving to MapScreen only *MapMarketPopup* widget without map is visible.

[image: This is how it looks like.]

### Code

*main.py*

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen

class LoginScreen(Screen):
    pass

class MapScreen(Screen):
    pass

GUI = Builder.load_file("main.kv")

class MainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return GUI

    def change_screen(self, screen_name):
        screen_manager = self.root.ids['screen_manager']
        # screen_manager.transition = WipeTransition()
        screen_manager.current = screen_name

MainApp().run()
```

*main.kv*

```
#:include loginscreen.kv
#:include mapscreen.kv

GridLayout:
    cols: 1
    ScreenManager:
        id: screen_manager
        LoginScreen:
            name: "login_screen"
            id: login_screen
        MapScreen:
            name: "map_screen"
            id: map_screen
```

*loginscreen.kv*

```
<LoginScreen>:
    Button:
        text: "Go to MapScreen"
        on_press: app.change_screen("map_screen")
```

*mapscreen.kv*

```
#:import MapView kivy.garden.mapview.MapView

<MapScreen@MapView>:
    lat: 52
    lon: 21
    zoom: 10
    double_tap_zoom: True
    on_lat:
        print(self.lat)
    on_lon:
        print(self.lon)
    MapMarkerPopup:
        lat: 52
        lon: 21
        Button:
            on_release:
                root.center_on(52,21)
                print(root.get_bbox())
```

### Question

Does anyone know where I made a mistake and how to correct it?

Comment: A better approach would be to include a `MapView` widget as a child of the `MapScreen`, rather than extending `MapView`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solution

The way how I solve this problem is by creating a dynamic class.

`MapScreen` is my second screen object and `MapView` widget used as a child of the `MapScreen`.

### Code

*mapscreen.kv*

```
#:import MapView kivy.garden.mapview.MapView

<MapScreen@Screen>:
    MapView:
        lat: 10
        lon: 10
        zoom: 10
        double_tap_zoom: True
        on_lat:
            print(self.lat)
        on_lon:
            print(self.lon)
        MapMarkerPopup:
            lat: 10
            lon: 10
            Button:
                on_release:
                    root.center_on(52,21)
                    print(root.get_bbox())
```

### Extra comment

What I also have found out I do not need to declare class in *main.py* when I will create a dynamic class.